# conditional assignment in dolphindb

Tags: matlab, dolphindb

A matlab-like conditional assignment statement works for vectors in dolphindb:

```
x=1 2 3
x[x<2]=2
x;
```

[2,2,3]

But looks like a conditional assignment statement on tables doesn't work in dolphindb:

```
t=table(1 2 3 as x, 4 5 6 as y)
t[`x][t[`x]<2]=2
```

Syntax Error: [line #2] Please use '==' rather than '=' as equal operator in non-sql expression.

Anyone knows how to do it on tables?

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
x = [1 1 4 3]';
y = [4 1 5 6]';
t = table(x,y);
t.x(x<2)  = 2
```

Results:

```
t = 
    x    y
    _    _
    2    4
    2    1
    4    5
    3    6
```